# How can I create parallel server connections on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

First, I wanted to use `parfor` directly in my compute so that I could use all my CPU cores. But, unfurtunately because of using sime global variable I couldn't do so. As a result, I came with this idea of running a MATLAB session as server and sone other MATLAB session as clients with tcp/ip connection.
I can connect a MATLAB session with another one, but if I'm going to connect the server to multiple sessions and wait for read, then I need parallel computing with parfor, but using parfor seems not to be compatible with fwrite function. Any advice?

```
sampleIterativeMK=randi([1 27],100,2);
sampleIterativeEQ=randi([1 3],100,1);
parfor iSample=1:2
    data=int8([sampleIterativeMK sampleIterativeEQ]);
    sampleIterativeMK((iSample-1)*50+1:iSample*50,1:2);
    s = whos('data');
    tcpipServer = tcpip('0.0.0.0',55000,'NetworkRole','Server');
    set(tcpipServer,'OutputBufferSize',s.bytes);
    fopen(tcpipServer);
    fwrite(tcpipServer,data(:),'int8');
    fclose(tcpipServer);
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to go. Could you describe what you are trying to implement?

Comment: @Daniel I want to use all my cores in a simulink simulation using sim function inside a loop in a M-File. So the common way is using parfor, but when you are using parfor, you can't use general variable or evalin function, and that's what we need, because a variable changes every step in the for loop. So I thought mayble we can run the loop single threaded in multi session of MATLAB using network connections, i.e. manually multi thread it

Comment: That's definitely not the right way to go. This will cause the iterations to wait on each other, killing the parallelism.

Comment: @Daniel there are too many job associated to each session, so if the right amount of iterations are associated to the session in the beginning, there will be not much of waiting.
FYI job association happens only on the beginning of the for, then another iteration happens on each session on a embedded for loop. So the size of loops are important in order to avoid waiting time which is not an issue right now.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel, you're asking the wrong question. Your question should be about how to run the Simulink model as part of a `parfor` loop, what you've tried and what problems you have come up against, with all the necessary details to reproduce the issue. It should perfectly doable to run a Simulink model as part of a `parfor` loop using multiples  cores, you're probably going about it the wrong way.